# Vb6 inserting password as a text box in a database

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have form of student registration and i have one password text box and I set the property PasswordChar  `*` 
In insert query I have write this statement

```
INSERT INTO student (student_id,first_name,Last_name,Email,password ) VALUES (' " & Text1.Text & " ' , ' " & Text2.Text & " ' , ' " & Text3.Text & " ',' " & Text4.Text & " ', ' " & Text5.Passwordchar & " ')"
```

When I test it i write 99999 as password but in my database is stored `*` and when I'm trying to login using the student id and the password I entered before giving me error
Is the insert of value password correct or not ?

Comment: Can't you just check in the database table and see what was inserted? And what was the error? Your insert looks correct (assuming you don't want to use parameters).

Comment: In password field is insert *

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong property. PasswordChar is the character used to hide the password on the screen. See [Using the Text Box Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733608(v=vs.60).aspx)

> PasswordChar specifies the character displayed in the text box. For example, if you want asterisks displayed in the password box, you specify * for the PasswordChar property in the Properties window. Regardless of what character a user types in the text box, an asterisk is displayed

You can get the value using the Text property.

Comment: If I change it to text property is stored the text sucessfuly but when I want to login using this password is giving me invalid login